# ldap_bind to secure LDAP server returns "Unknown CA"

Tags: php, apache, ssl, active-directory, ldap

Attempting to configure a PHP app to securely authenticate against a remote LDAP server and am running into a wall.   ldap tools are installed and I'm able to connect to the remote LDAP server, but checking the error_log, I'm seeing

```
Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
```

This is triggered by a call to `ldap_bind` in my application.  `ldap_connect` doesn't return errors.  I've verified that I can connect to the ldap server using:

```
openssl s_client -connect ldap.service.company.com:636

SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : AES256-SHA
Session-ID: (snip)
Session-ID-ctx: 
Master-Key: (snip)
Key-Arg   : None
Krb5 Principal: None
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
Start Time: 1389213908
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

`tcpdump` and `wireshark` were utilized to monitor and analyze network traffic on an attempted LDAP authentication from my application.

```
tcpdump -s 1514 port 636 -w capture_file
```

`wireshark` revealed a fatal error:

```
TLSv1   Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)
```

Apache's ssl.conf config points to files with correct permissions, and no errors are shown when starting/restarting httpd.

Help/pointers appreciated.  Let me know if I can supply more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a signed certificate on your ldap host on the 636 port. The client (your PHP server) is rejecting this certificate as the certificate authority in not in its known/valid ca's. 
Either get a real SSL certificate or install the certificate path on your webserver.

If, and only If, your webserver and ldap host are within the same network and is solely managed nu you and youare sure no data can be captured between the hosts, you could choose to not use the SSL/TLS version of the ldap protocol..

Comment: We have a signed certificate from InCommon for our app server (app.company.com).  This is referenced in Apache's ssl.conf file, and the cert is readable by apache.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorant sounding question, but what exactly is the "certificate path" - are we talking of the directory path to the InCommon certificate?  If so, how is that path "installed"?

Comment: Path = dir path to incommon indeed! But how is the ssl.conf helping your ldap functions to 'know' the ssl?

Comment: Will ldap_bind use the SSL settings in Apache's config, or something else?  You mentioned that I may need to install the path.  What tool is used for this so I can read up on the man page?

Comment: No, i think you should use /etc/ openldap/ ldap.conf ( or check the server configuration for the exact file ) :) ssl.conf is for having your apache host an ssl enabled site

Comment: Ok getting clearer now.  So I would need to specify the server Incommon cert (for app.company.com) in `/etc/opendlap/ldap.conf` -- and that's what you mean by install?

Comment: Got it - I after fixing the paths it still didn't work.  I then read where I needed to run `/usr/sbin/cacertdir_rehash` on the `TLS_CACERTDIR` directory specified under `/etc/opendlap/ldap.conf`.  After that, LDAP is working as expected.  Thanks again!